# Location of symchk

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I've read about `symchk` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I can't figure out where it's located on my disk (or how to get it). I've installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and would think that it's included. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See MS KB (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503). SymChk is delivered with Debugging Tools for Windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009).

Comment: Strange is that the debug tools aren't installed with Visual Studio. So, after installing the Windows SDK one can find symchk under `C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)` (or similar).

Comment: I found mine in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64`