# How to load all Windows Symbols from server, starting with W10 version 1803 / build 17134?

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I used to download [Offline symbol packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols) (Debug symbol MSIs) and use only them since it's we don't need to wait for slow downloading as we go in debugging. However this feature is no longer existing starting with Windows 10 1803/build 17134 ([Features removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-1803-removed-features)).

How can I fetch *all of them* once and for all ?

Comment: By using Symchk.exe utility, I would venture. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symchk-command-line-options

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux `symchk` doesn't fit the *I want them all* need.

Comment: Symchk.exe is right tool

Comment: @Soleil, Whether magicandre1981's suggestion is helpful for you? Actually I agree with him, since the previous feature has been removed, you could think about using the command line as a workaround now:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-a-manifest-file-with-symchk

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Didn't give it a try yet. I couldn't install symcheck from VS installer, and it seems it won't be started from powershell. It looked like it's an old workaround, so I was looking for something more modern or up to date.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Furthermore, it is said to be part of  Windows SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/index so, it means I should have installed it from VS installer, but I couldn't find it in the folders.

Comment: (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits` then `sudo find . -name "symchk.exe"` or  `Get-ChildItem -Recurse "symchk.exe"`)

Comment: @Soleil, It is delivered with Debugging Tools for Windows(Not in VS IDE): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414769/location-of-symchk

Comment: @Soleil, Did you resolve this issue in your side using this command line? If you have any issue or latest information, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks for the heads up. It looks like it works but it really sounds and looks like a workaround. I got symbols for many apps I'm not using for Windows development (such as mssql), I'm getting lots of 'FAILED' for dlls and other files. It's also extremely slow, download/exchanges are stalling recurrently. `symchk` is also from non powershell world. One question: how do I know that everything I need is there ? I mean, how come binaries from SDK are only in c:\windows ? And last, how to download only symbols for whole SDK ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run [this command to get all PDBs](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-is-no-longer-providing-offline-msi-symbol-packages/) for all Windows files:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\symchk.exe" /r c:\windows /s SRV*c:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Comment: How do I know for which build I'm downloading ? How do I change the build ?

Comment: this downloads the PDBs for the current installed Windows. To downlaod other PDBs, mount the install.wim of the Windows you want and change the folder in the commandline to the mounted WIM folder

Comment: Thanks. How can I download only symbols for Windows SDK ? For instance, the command is downloading symbols for mssql and many other programs that are not part of the SDK.

Comment: change **c:\windows** in commandline to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10** to get PDBs for all SDK files

Comment: This doesn't work any more. For all files it returns FAILED  - mismatched or not found

Comment: @AntonKukoba post more details. not all files have symbols on symbol server.

Comment: I can't download user32.dll symbols neither for 1703 nor for 1803. 

C:\Users\kukoba.anton>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\symchk.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\user32.dll" /s SRV*c:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
SYMCHK: user32.dll           FAILED  - wuser32.pdb mismatched or not found

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 1
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 0

And I'm pretty sure it all worked well a month ago.

Comment: @AntonKukoba it looks like Microsofts symbol server is down. I see gateway timeout error in Windbg. try it again later

Comment: @AntonKukoba symbol server is up again. try it again.

Comment: Would just like to point out, I found a way to more easily get the target symbols download without mounting the install.wim for your build: `symchk.exe /r \\[your_target_hostname]\C$\Windows /s SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` It pulls the symbols from a live machine across the network.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, and symchk.exe works just fine.
But this application is far to slow and antiquate.
Based on the [PDB-Downloader](https://github.com/rajkumar-rangaraj/PDB-Downloader) I created a PowerShell script to download from massive file lists.
Do check it out!

[Get-PdbSymbol](https://github.com/FranciscoNabas/PowerShellPublic/blob/main/Get-PdbSymbol.ps1)

It requires PowerShell 7.3 or newer.

In action:

[image: Get-PdbSymbol]

Comment: please post text code, no pictures

Comment: There's a link to the code on the message.